# Xcode Project Source File auto Copy

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm currently facing a problem with c++ on xcode. When I do fopen("verShader.vsh","r"), it returns NULL pointer.

If I put verShader.vsh to /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HollowWorld‌​-hghymrkhtbuguoaiwgp‌​tundpakuz/Build/Prod‌​ucts/Debug the fopen() will work. However the file in the same dir of main.cpp which is /Users/apple/Developer/C++/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.

Is there anyway that when I build the project it could automatically copy "verShader.vsh" to the dir of execution file?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by add "copy files" in the build phases
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> it returns NULL pointer as the working space is .../DerivedData/... while the "verShader.vsh" is put in the dir of main.cpp

That's because you're using the file name "verShader.vsh" without providing the path to the file. Mac (and iOS) application bundles have a specific structure, with all the resources stored in specific subdirectories apart from the executable file or the working directory.

> Is there anyway that when I build the project it could automatically copy "verShader.vsh" to the dir of execution file?

That's the wrong approach -- you'd still need to know the path of the file that you want to copy, and once you know that, you might as well just read it where it is instead of copying it. In Objective-C or Swift, that'd be easy:

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"verShader" ofType:@"vsh"];

In C++ you can do the same thing using Core Foundation:

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef url = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, CFSTR("verShader"), CFSTR("vsh"), NULL);
char path[255];  // space for the path
Boolean success = CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(url, true, path, 255);
```

(Warning: it's been a while since I needed to use Core Foundation, so use the code above as a starting point but don't be shy about checking the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html) yourself and making any necessary corrections.)

Once you have the path, you can use it with the usual C/C++ file routines like `fopen()`

Comment: I tried CFURLRef burl = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(mainBundle); CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(url, true, path, 255); and the burl returns the dir of the /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-hghymrkhtbuguoaiwgptundpakuz/Build/Products/Debug. But the verShader.vsh is located in the same dir of main.cpp

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand my issue, if I put verShader.vsh to /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HollowWorld-hghymrkhtbuguoaiwgptundpakuz/Build/Products/Debug the fopen() will work. However the file in the same dir of main.cpp which is /Users/apple/Developer/C++/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.

Comment: At run time there *is* no `main.cpp` file -- that source file will have been compiled and turned into executable code. If you want `verShader.vsh` to be a file built into your program that your code can access, then you should make it a *resource*, so that it'll be copied into the app's bundle when the app is built. If you just want it to be a file somewhere in the file system, then you need to write code that determines the *path* to the file and uses it rather than just expecting it to be in the working directory. I assumed that it was a resource, but either way you should provide the path.

Comment: how do i make it as a resource?

Comment: Projects typically have a "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase, and you'd just make sure that `verShader.vsh` is included there. But looks like you found a similar solution with your Copy Files build phase.